# Pegando Lista dentro de lista em um Objeto - JS - JQUERY -

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho esse objeto 'data'

```
const data = {
  "mobs": [{    
    "movs": [{
      "originadaAqui": true,
      "desabilitada": false,
      "cancelada": false,
      "descricao": "",
      "exTipoMovimentacao": "ANEXACAO_DE_ARQUIVO_AUXILIAR",
      "complemento": "",
      "parte": {
        "cadastrante": {
          "sigla": "DER42466",
          "siglaAmpliada": "DER42466",
          "descricao": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "iniciais": "DER42466",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        },
        "lotaCadastrante": {
          "sigla": "UNITESTE",
          "siglaAmpliada": "UNITESTE",
          "descricao": "Unidade Teste",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Unidade Teste",
          "iniciais": "UT",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        },
        "lotaResp": {
          "sigla": "UNITESTE",
          "siglaAmpliada": "UNITESTE",
          "descricao": "Unidade Teste",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Unidade Teste",
          "iniciais": "UT",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        },
        "lotaSubscritor": {
          "sigla": "UNITESTE",
          "siglaAmpliada": "UNITESTE",
          "descricao": "Unidade Teste",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Unidade Teste",
          "iniciais": "UT",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        },
        "resp": {
          "sigla": "DER42466",
          "siglaAmpliada": "DER42466",
          "descricao": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "iniciais": "DER42466",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        },
        "subscritor": {
          "sigla": "DER42466",
          "siglaAmpliada": "DER42466",
          "descricao": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "descricaoAmpliada": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
          "iniciais": "DER42466",
          "siglaOrgao": "DER"
        }
      },
      "dtIniMov": "May 18, 2022 11:03:10 AM",
      "dtRegMovDDMMYYHHMMSS": "18/05/22 11:03:10",
      "descrTipoMovimentacao": "Anexação de Arquivo Auxiliar",
      "idMov": 531000,
      "duracaoSpan": 0,
      "duracaoSpanExibirCompleto": 0,
      "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
      "lotaCadastranteSigla": "UNITESTE",
      "exTipoMovimentacaoSigla": "Anexação de Arquivo Auxiliar",
      "tempoRelativo": "2 meses",
      "podeExibirNoSigale": false,
      "acoes": [{
          "icone": "image",
          "nome": "rodovia-online - Copia 2.jpg",
          "nameSpace": "/app/arquivo",
          "acao": "exibir",
          "pode": true,
          "params": {
            "sigla": "DERCON202200001",
            "arquivo": "DERCON202200001:531000",
            "id": "531000"
          },
          "explicacao": "Permitido porque nome do arquivo não é nulo",
          "post": false
        },
        {
          "nome": "Cancelar",
          "nameSpace": "/app/expediente/mov",
          "acao": "cancelar",
          "pode": true,
          "params": {
            "sigla": "DERCON202200001",
            "id": "531000"
          },
          "explicacao": "Permitido porque não está cancelada a movimentação e não está sem efeito",
          "post": false
        }
      ]
    }],

    "marcadoresEmHtml": "Assinado"
  }],
  "sigla": "DER-CON-2022/00001",
  "fisicoOuEletronico": "Documento Eletrônico",
  "modelo": "Gestão de Documento e Informações: Convite",
  "tipoFormaDocumento": "expediente",
  "cadastranteString": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
  "marcas": [{
      "id": 974623,
      "dtIni": "May 18, 2022 11:00:38 AM",
      "idMarcador": 75,
      "descr": "Assinado",
      "idTipoMarca": 1,
      "descrTipoMarca": "SIGA-EX",
      "idPessoaIni": 32466,
      "siglaPessoa": "DER42466",
      "nomePessoa": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
      "idLotacaoIni": 103774,
      "siglaLotacao": "UNITESTE",
      "nomeLotacao": "Unidade Teste",
      "idMob": 582679,
      "siglaMob": "DER-CON-2022/00001-A",
      "identificadorMob": "A",
      "descricaoComDatas": "Assinado"
    },
    {
      "id": 974624,
      "dtIni": "May 18, 2022 11:32:51 AM",
      "idMarcador": 62,
      "descr": "Documento Assinado com Senha",
      "idTipoMarca": 1,
      "descrTipoMarca": "SIGA-EX",
      "idPessoaIni": 32466,
      "siglaPessoa": "DER42466",
      "nomePessoa": "Emily Leite Marighetti",
      "idMob": 582183,
      "siglaMob": "DER-CON-2022/00001",
      "identificadorMob": "Geral",
      "descricaoComDatas": "Documento Assinado com Senha"
    }
  ]
};
```

estou tentando mostrar em uma tabela os dados do array **movs[ ]** que esta dentro do **mobs[ ]**

consegui pegar os dados do array **marcas[ ]**, mas nao sei como pegar os dados em listas dentro de listas

codigo abaixo peguei os dados do **marcas[ ]**

```
const linhas = $.map(data.marcas, function(marca) {
  return `<tr>
              <td> ${marca.descr} </td>
              <td> ${marca.descrTipoMarca} </td>
              <td> ${marca.nomePessoa} </td>
              <td> ${marca.siglaLotacao} </td>
              <td> ${marca.siglaMob} </td>
              <td> ${marca.siglaMob} </td>
              </tr>`;
}).join('');

console.log(linhas);
$("#tabela").append(linhas);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Alexsir_Wolf_00/8uny9wxf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma. Primeiro pega a lista movs:

```
let movs = data.mobs[0].movs;
```

Com a lista em mãos, você monta ela com o método map, da maneira que pretende usar, por exemplo colocando as ações em botões da tabela:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Tipo Movimentação</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>


let movs = data.mobs[0].movs;
let rows = movs.map(item => {
    let acoes = item.acoes.map(acao => {
        return `<a href="https://api.com${acao.nameSpace}"><i class="btn"> 
        </i>${acao.nome}</a>`;
    });

    return `
        <tr>
            <td>${item.idMov}</td>
            <td>${item.descrTipoMovimentacao}</td>
            <td>${acoes.join('')}</td>
        </tr>
    `; 
});

$("table tbody").append(rows.join(''));
```

Esse é um exemplo de como se manipular e transformar o objeto, ainda tem métodos como filter etc..
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: consegui resolver exatemente assim, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou amigo!

Answer (score -1):

Nessa estrutura que você passou, os dados de `movs` estão dentro de um **array** em `mobs`, você pode acessar através do elemento diretamente, já que só tem um, exemplo:
`data.mobs[0].movs`

ou pode criar um laço de repetição e acessar o elemento de maneira iterativa, exemplo:

```js
data.mobs.forEach(function(el){
     console.log(el.movs);
});
```